# Switch to Intel Graphics from NVIDIA Prime profile is not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

My system (Ubuntu 18.04) was using Intel GPU earlier, and I installed Nvidia drivers and it started using Nvidia GPU. Now, I wanted to switch back to INTEL GPU and tried doing that using PRIME Profiles.

`sudo prime-select intel`

`Info: the intel profile is already set`

But apparently the GPU doesn't switch.
[Ubuntu "About" Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moShn.png)

Could someone help?